# How can I query the Hadoop JobHistoryServer?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to query the JHS to verify that it isn't down.

If I wanted to do this for the ResourceManager, I might do [Cluster.getClusterStatus()](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/f67237cbe7bc48a1b9088e990800b37529f1db2a/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Cluster.java#L276). This would make a call to the RM and return an error if we can't reach the cluster.

How can I do the same for the JobHistoryServer?

Comment: It looks like the JobHistory server has a REST API. Have you tried using it to essentially ping the service? My guess is that it would return a certain code if it's down. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HistoryServerRest.html#Response_Examples

Comment: Is there a way for me to get the JobHistoryServer URL? The best I can find is [Cluster.getJobHistoryUrl](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/f67237cbe7bc48a1b9088e990800b37529f1db2a/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Cluster.java#L362), but I need to pass a jobId to it. I don't have access to `client`, so I can't call `client.getJobHistoryDir()` directly.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. try your namenode with the port 19888 in the form:

http://<namenode address>:19888/ or http://<namenode address>:19888/jobhistory